# Textbox border becomes thicker after rendering RDLC report to pdf

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I am making `rdlc` report and I am rendering it to `pdf`, but for some reason textboxs' borders become thicker after this process. More strange is that if I copy (only location and ZIndex properties change) one of the textboxes (which border becomes thicker) in another place, the border of copied textbox isn't thick.

[image]

This is the result.
[image]

Comment: Here's a similar solved problem: https://www.telerik.com/forums/textbox-borders-don-t-work-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem only in `Microsoft edge` (while opening generated pdf file in it). My report looks nice in `Opera` and `Google Chrome` browsers. I tried to report this problem to Microsoft, but their web page told me that it wasn't able to identify I was person or not.. :)